# Unite a forest if you know each tree's parent

Tags: algorithms, graphs, data-structures, trees

I have a forest of Tries, each `forest[i]` is a Trie. `forest[0]` contains the root node  to all the others. I want to recursively unite all of the Tries if I know each Trie's parent.. how can I do that?

This is my data structure and this is how I am using it.

```
typedef struct trie
{
    int id;
    int parent;
    struct trie *child;
    struct trie *sibling;
} *Trie;
Trie *forest;
```

EDIT with photos:

We have 2 tries here:
[image: first]
[image: second]

If node `4` which is the "root" of the right Trie had the parent `9` for example, I would  like to "unite" `9` to `4` and get the bigger Trie.

I would like to implement a function

```
Trie uniteForest(Trie root, Trie *forest, int id)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

That returns me the final "Trie".

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. What do you mean by "unite"? Do you just make one node a child of the other? Also what is a Trie's parent? Is this different than the root? Also, if these are specifically Trie's then uniting them is non trivial if you want to maintain properties of a Trie. For instance when merging a trie of {his, her, him} and a trie of {hero, heavy, hippy}. Could you provide a small picture/diagram of an example of what you're looking for?

Comment: @ryan yeah i will provide pictures in 10 mins

Comment: @ryan Check the edit! I hope my question is more clear now

Comment: The "Trie" property is not based on the numbers, those are just an example

Comment: Would you not just make 4 the child of 9 and be done? What should happen if you called `unite(9, 8)`? Also, are you referring to [this Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) because it doesn't seem like you are? You may also be interested in the [disjoint set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) data structure cause that seems similar to what you're trying to do by "union"-ing two disjoint sets.

Comment: Also, can you specifically define what it means to "unite" a node A and a node B? This might help clear up some confusion as I don't quite get it from this example.

Comment: @ryan To "unite" means that ```4``` should be ```9->child``` or something like ```9->child->sibling```

Comment: @ryan I would like but what if I had a third "Trie" and ```4``` had the parent in that trie and that trie had the parent in the first Trie, how would I treat that?

Comment: I mean to define "unite" in general, not for this example. The definition should be something like this definition of [union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure#Union): "_Union(x,y)_ uses _Find_ to determine the roots of the trees x and y belong to. If the roots are distinct, the trees are combined by attaching the root of one to the root of the other."

Comment: @ryan Okay, then "Union(x,y), Determine the "parent" node in x and make y a child of x", is that okay? Since in my structure every "root" of every "tree" has a "parent" in some other "tree" from the forest